# Imprimir ciclo while en un TextArea que se encuentra en otra clase Java

Tags: java, clase

Tengo este programa que realiza un ping a un host especificado.

```
public class PingTool {

private String ip = "";
private int port;
private int times;
private String hostaddr = "";
String resultado;


public void setDireccion(String ip, int port, int times){
    this.ip = ip;
    this.port = port;
    this.times = times;
}

//Metodo que ejecuta el programa.
public void exec(){

    try { 
        hostaddr = InetAddress.getByName(ip).getHostAddress();.           
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) { 
        System.out.println("El host ingresado es incorrecto."); 
        System.exit(0); 
    }

    resultado = "Haciendo ping a "+ip+" ("+hostaddr+") "+times+" veces en el puerto "+port+"...\n";

    int total = 0;
    long totalping = 0;
    Socket s = null;

    while(total < times) {
        total++;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try {
            SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(hostaddr, port);
            s = new Socket();
            s.connect(sockaddr, 1000);
        } catch(SocketTimeoutException e) {
            resultado = "Respuesta desde ["+hostaddr+"]: Tiempo de espera agotado.";
            continue;
        } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
        } catch(IOException e) {
        }

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        totalping += (end-start);
        long totaltime = (end-start);
        long avg = (long)(totalping/total);

        if(totaltime <= 0){
            totaltime++;
            resultado = "Respuesta desde "+hostaddr+" Tiempo: "+ "<" + totaltime + "ms" +" Average: "+avg;
        }else{
            resultado = "Respuesta desde "+hostaddr+" Tiempo: "+ totaltime + "ms" +" Average: "+avg;
        }
    }

    long avg = (long)(totalping/total);

    resultado = "\nResultado de ping para: " + hostaddr;
    resultado = "\nAverage request - " + avg;

}
```

}

Y tengo otra clase en la cual tengo la interfaz grafica en la que se mostrara el resultado es un textarea.

```
    PingTool pingTool = new PingTool();

    String ip = campoIP.getText();
    int port = Integer.parseInt(campoPort.getText());
    int times = Integer.parseInt(campoTimes.getText());

    pingTool.setDireccion(ip, port, times);
    pingTool.exec();
    resultadoPing.append(result + "\n");
```

Lo que no puedo lograr hacer es imprimir el resultado el textarea cada vuelta del ciclo, por ejemplo si quiero hacer ping 10 veces en el textarea debería aparecer esos 10 resultados.
Pero lo único que consigo es imprimir el ultimo valor que se le asigna a la variable que contiene el resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se entiende bien en que parte estas mandando las cosas a tu view.

Sin embargo, en ningun momento estan armando una cadena con todos los resultados.

mira por ejemplo:

```
resultado = "Respuesta desde "+hostaddr+" Tiempo: "+ totaltime + "ms" +" Average: "+avg;
```

estas lineas, sobreescriben siempre el valor de resultado, no lo estan agregando a los que estaban antes, por lo tanto, siempre queda el ultimo valor.

deberias usar algo del estilo:

```
resultado += "Respuesta desde "+hostaddr+" Tiempo: "+ totaltime + "ms" +" Average: "+avg;
```

Esto ultimo apenda la nueva cadena, a la cadena que estaba de antes... y eso para todos los lugares donde agregues datos al resultado.

Answer (score 0):

lo que yo ago es concatenar todas las respuestas.Concatena lo que tienes dentro del while pero al ultimo de cada interacion agrégale un ";",en la vista solo haces TextArea.setText(Respuesta.replace(";","\n")).